# Developer permissions

Tags: permissions, system-apps, android-device-manager

Is there a way to remove or deny permission of system packages
Example an app has permission to com.android.vending.BILLING?
I have root access

Comment: You can only deny dangerous permissions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions

Comment: What about changing apk manifest.xml

Comment: I mean change it then install it will it work?  By the way i'm not removing permission to a service that is needed or the app won't run i just chanhe permission for unnecessary services